# Meaning of "Circle around with"

Tags: meaning, phrases

All too often my boss will say to me "I'll circle around with you later"

I assume it means "I'll catch up with you later" or something of the sort, but I feel the "circle" implies some sort of redundancy or endlessness loop of checking in on me.  Is that right?

Comment: Ask him what he means! If my boss said that to me I'd wonder if it's a new line in buzzword bingo, is he a weirdo? or perhaps he's a pathological vulture??

Comment: "circle back" generally means I'll get back to you. It could also imply checking with another person about something first before getting back to the person. Another example: "go ask John and we'll circle back." I think "circle around" in the context you provided means the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [BeeDictionary](http://www.beedictionary.com/meaning/circle_around), "circle around" means to move around in a circular motion. That does imply redundancy or endlessness doesn't it?

In the case of your boss saying "with", it kinds of changes the meaning a bit. It implies that **you** are the one doing the circling around, and that the boss will join you in your circuit later on (hence, the "catch-up" meaning).

By "circling around" the boss doesn't mean endless or pointless wandering, but rather he means by what you do everyday, your normal tasks and jobs or errands etc. Thus, he would join you later in order to catch up with you.